# Reconfigure TFS2008 + VS2010 after renaming Computer

Tags: sql-server

I had to rename a computer which was running TFS2008 with SQL2008 r2 on the same server..
Manage to get to connect  SQL2008 R2 running with new name.. 
How can I re-configure the TFS to point to newly named ( NewServer\MyNamedSqlInstance) ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *possibly* belongs on ServerFault but I don't know how common it is for IT to manage TFS.  Most places I've worked it's handled by the build engineer who is a developer.

[How to: Move from a Single-Server to a Dual-Server Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404854(v=VS.90).aspx)

Comment: I'm torn on whether these belong on SF or SO.  I don't think there's as much of a TFS community over on SF.

Comment: Yes, that's the dilemma of my choosen career.  I'm part SysAdmin, part Build Engineer, part Setup Developer and part Developer.  People like myself live a double life.

Comment: I vote for leave it here since Microsoft posted that article on MSDN and not TechNet.